# React prop-types expecting function with valid PropTypes definition

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

At some point my project began complaining about most declared PropTypes definitions, whether declared in home-built components or grabbed from well-trusted libraries in npm.

Example Console Warning:

> Failed prop type: ListGrid: prop type `serverPaged` is invalid; it
>   must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but
>   received `boolean`.

Example copied src:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // package.json dependencies: "prop-types": "^15.6.1",

//...

ListGrid.propTypes = {
  //...
  serverPaged: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

Example Component which caused warning:

[image: Boolean definition]

How can these errors flooding the console be resolved?

Comment: Best way to start debugging is back out the contributed components. My guess is that there is a bug somewhere in one of them. How many do you have?

Comment: can you try to run `rm -rf node_modules` and then again `yarn install` it looks something is broken in your project as code looks fine ....

Comment: `del /F /S /Q node_modules` `rmdir /S /Q node_modules npm start` `npm install`  did not resolve the issue.   There are 27 dependencies in package.json.  Lost on how to resolve without going through and removing packages 1 by 1.